# Can the derivative in a system of ODEs be replaced with a derivative matrix?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In [this video](https://youtu.be/TgKwz5Ikpc8?t=412), the derivative is presented in the form of a matrix.  Given this, can the derivative in a system of ODEs, such as $\vec{x}' = A\vec{x} + \vec{f}$, be replaced with multiplication on the left by the derivative matrix?  Does $\vec{x}$ have to contain only polynomials for this to work?  Is there another derivative matrix that works for vectors of functions in general?

Comment: You need to add more detail, it is a bit much to expect folks to watch a video to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have $n$ unknown functions, say 
$$x_1,...,x_n$$all of the same variable, say $t$ and another given $n$ functions, say $$f_1,...,f_n$$,also of the same variable $t.$ You also have an $n \times n$ matrix of constants, $A.$ You are trying to find the functions $$x_1(t),...,x_n(t)$$ subject to the condition $$\begin{bmatrix}dx_1/dt\\.\\.\\.\\dx_n/dt \end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}x_1(t)\\.\\.\\.\\x_n(t)\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}f_1(t)\\.\\.\\.\\f_n(t)\end{bmatrix}$$